# Difference between emulator and hardware kits for android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-emulator, gps, emulation

I am a student of Third year, CSE. I have mobile applications development laboratory in next semester.

As I am already developing apps in android, my department wants me to take up the job of doing exercises. Also they need to buy some toolkits for this Laboratory like **AM335x Starter kit carter-A8 processor, 7" TFT with Touch Screen Display** etc.

My question is, Can we test apps which uses using GPS and Bluetooth permissions in normal Android Virtual Device emulators or do we need to buy these Kits for testing those apps? If so please explain me the difference between them.

Comment: You can use "Genymotion" which emulates GPS and other sensors. Android Virtual Device lacks a lots of features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can stimulate GPS on AVD but bluetooth is not possible.There are few more limitations as per [official doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#limitations)

On other end Genymotion, its free version has limitation too.For more info refer [one](http://jenshen.net/mobileapps/genymotion-android-emulator-alternative/) and [two](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/legal/terms-and-conditions)

To be honest you need atleast one real device for proper end to end testing, hence having an hardware support is not bad if college is allowing it.

Comment: I agree that having a real device is very helpful - particularly there are user interface issues (especially with the touch screen and user's fat fingers) that just don't show up with the mouse and emulator.